# ESP8266 GET REPLY ERROR 501

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to build a home automation system and i am unable to get data from a website using the arduino sketch, however i am able to get data from the website when i enter the AT commands into the serial monitor.Below is my sketch:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(4,5);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
  esp8266.println("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  esp8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\"www.homeautomationserver.com\",80 \r\n");
  delay(2000);
  esp8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,75");
  esp8266.println("GET /f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  esp8266.println("Host:www.homeautomationserver.com\r\n\r\n");
}

void loop(){

  if (esp8266.available()){
    Serial.write(esp8266.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()){
    esp8266.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

I get a 501 not Implemented error from the server.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001020.htm

Comment: You should really include `Connection: close` in your headers as well, so the server doesn't try and keep the connection open longer than needed.

Comment: `Content-length: ???` might help too.  (??? should be the message size)

Comment: @Matt Content-length would be 0 - there is no body there to have a length. It's not *strictly* needed, especially if the sending pipe is manually closed by the client.

Comment: Maybe you should replace `esp8266.println()` with `esp8266.print()`, because you already append "\r\n" in your strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use you favourite web browser and retrieve the page http://www.homeautomationserver.com/f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt ?
If you can then the problem is with your client, if not its with the address you are requesting or the server.

The fact you are getting a 501 error indicates that GET is not supported for this resource.  So check that you are using the correct method?

Get yourself a REST console (there is an add-on for chrome and plenty of others) try typing the command in manually to see if you can identify the fault.

Look at Wikipedia for a list of error codes, it might give you a clue as to what is wrong.

And don't you need a AT+CIPSEND after you have printed the http packet?

Comment: `And don't you need a AT+CIPSEND after you have printed the http packet?` - no that comes beforehand. The numbers indicate how many bytes you are about to send so it knows how many to expect.

Comment: @Majenko - OK, thanks for the correction, I just saw an example that had the send after the header, maybe it was sending an empty body(?).

Comment: If the send is after any form of data (including the header) the data will be interpreted as ESP8266 AT commands and will fail. The example you found must be horribly broken.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have tried using your code and this time i am not receiving any reply from the server. i have also noticed that using my code i sometimes receive a 400 error -bad request as well followed by the 501 error after a few tries .i am so confused with the error codes generated by the server.

Comment: Sorry Matt i was trying to reply to Majenko and thank you for your reply as well, I know the issue is with my sketch but cannot figure out what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in these lines:

```
esp8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,75");
esp8266.println("GET /f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n");
esp8266.println("Host:www.homeautomationserver.com\r\n\r\n");
```

You are mistakenly using `println()` instead of `print()` when sending the data. That imposes its own `<CR><LF>` sequence on the end of the lines, yet you are adding the `<CR><LF>` manually.  You are also incorrectly specifying 75 characters to send, so the result of all that is:

```
GET /f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n              37
\r\n                                                  2
Host:www.homeautomationserver.com\r\n                35
\r                                                    1
                                                   ----
                                                     75
```

I.e., your request is garbled. You need to change the `println()` to `print()` for the data printing and make sure the character count is correct:

```
esp8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,74");
esp8266.print("GET /f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n");
esp8266.print("Host:www.homeautomationserver.com\r\n\r\n");

GET /f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n              37
Host:www.homeautomationserver.com\r\n                35
\r\n                                                  2
                                                   ----
                                                     74
```

You should also include more detail and commands in your headers. Things like the length of the body (0 bytes) and the fact that the connection should be closed, and there really should be a space after the colon on the Host: header:

```
esp8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,113");
esp8266.print("GET /f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n");
esp8266.print("Connection: close\r\n");
esp8266.print("Content-Length: 0\r\n");
esp8266.print("Host: www.homeautomationserver.com\r\n\r\n");

GET /f/pw9e1acqx7yb0gl.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n              37
Connection: close\r\n                                19
Content-Length: 0\r\n                                19
Host: www.homeautomationserver.com\r\n               36
\r\n                                                  2
                                                  -----
                                                    113
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have tried using your code and this time i am not receiving any reply from the server. i have also noticed that using my code i sometimes receive a 400 error -bad request as well followed by the 501 error after a few tries .i am so confused with the error codes generated by the server.